# Process files in a folder with powershell

Tags: powershell, zip

I made a very basic ps1 script that works right. This script processes some file that originally was in a zip file. Now I have many zip in a folder: is it possible write a script that

- scans a folder searching for zip file
- unzips the first zip to a folder

  Code:

  ```
  Get-ChildItem "C:\INFOLDER\FILENAME.zip" | % {
      & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" "x" $_.FullName "-oOUTFOLDER"
  }
  ```

  This does work.
- launches my ps1 script and wait its work
- processes other zips

How can I get this to work?

Comment: You can use `Get-ChildItem` to scan folder, feed that to a `variable`. It will be an array containg `zip` files path. Then use your command mentioned above to unzip it (you may use `foreach` loop).   Use Remove-Item cmdlet to remove zip file.

Comment: `"C:\INFOLDER\FILENAME.zip"` -> `"C:\INFOLDER\*.zip"`